# I just want to add a radio buttons to my content type

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I am creating a new content type in Drupal 7 and I would like to add some radio buttons as content types.  This is surprisingly difficult to do.  I have enabled field and options modules but I have yet to see radio buttons show up as an option for numeric or text fields.  How do I do this?

Update: I do not have 'select option' or 'list' as a select-able field type

[image: Here is what I have]

Comment: Are you sure, that under modules you have the List module activated? It's in core.

Comment: No, I did not have it activated.  Thanks, that solved the problem

Comment: It's strange that the 'option' module did not have the 'list' module as one of its requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose the `list` field type - this will display radio buttons.  `List` core module will need to be enabled.

Comment: I don't see 'select option' in my field type drop down.  DO I need to activate a module to get this?

Comment: Typo! updated - it is list